# Any good place to learn Javascript Browser Object Model?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently reading [Professional Javascript for web developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118026691) and in the section for BOM, there's a lot of talking and it's really not helping reading lots of paragraphs and tiny snippets of code every now and then.

I'm looking for a good website, tutorial that demonstrates the BOM well. I've searched a lot but all i'm getting is the DOM stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The DOM **is** the "browser object model." Good references would be:

- [DOM Core 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM 2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM Core 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)
- [DOM Events 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/)
- [DOM Events 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/)
- [HTML5 Web Applications APIs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis)

And as for meta-refs, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is quite good.

[This blog post](http://bay-six.blogspot.in/2013/01/javascript-browser-object-model.html) gives a nice diagram of the various objects in addition to the pure DOM that nearly all browsers provide.

Comment: All good references, for someone learning javascript there is also the list of books and on–line resources at the [comp.lang.javascript](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/#books) news group FAQ.

Comment: @RobG: I read the question as about learning the DOM (or what the OP calls the "browser object model"), not learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools together some standard Browser Objects:

[JavaScript and HTML DOM Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp)

- Browser Objects

  - Window
  - Navigator
  - Screen
  - History
  - Location

Some non-standard Gecko and firefox only objects in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window).